# Como obter método e classe de onde o erro foi lançado

Tags: typescript

Possuo uma classe de erro customizada na minha aplicação.

```
export class AppError extends Error {
  public readonly message: string;

  public readonly status: number;

  public readonly data: any;

  public readonly params: ErrorParams;

  constructor(
    message: string,
    status = 400,
    data?: any,
    params?: Omit<ErrorParams, 'time'>
  ) {
    super();

    this.params = {
      internalStatusCode: params?.internalStatusCode || null,
      severity: params?.severity || ErrorSeverity.NOT_DEFINED,
      time: new Date().getTime(),
      service: params?.service || null,
      location: params?.location || null,
    };

    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
    this.data = data;
  }
}
```

No objeto `params` sempre que lanço um erro a partir desta classe, passo para ele as propriedades `location` e `service` de forma manual.

```
throw new AppError(
  'Error',
  500, 
  {}, 
  { location: 'Method foo', service: 'Service bar'}
)
```

Gostaria de que alguma forma, seja por um decorator, ou outra técnica, não fosse necessário adicionar essas propriedades manualmente, a própria classe se encarregaria de inserir estas informações levando em conta o contexto em que esta sendo lançada.

Alguém possui alguma ideia de como fazer isso ?

Comment: Você pode tentar utilizar a propriedade `Error.prototype.stack`, fazer alguma coisa tipo um _parse_ simples. Mas saiba que a string varia conforme a implementação, o que pode dificultar um pouco.

Comment: Neste caso da stack o máximo que consegui ver que posso é aproveitar dali é recuperar o nome do arquivo com regex onde teve a exceção, o que não me é muito útil.